# How to fix JHtmlBehavior::formvalidator not found

Tags: php, joomla3.3, joomla3.4

I tried to upgrade from Joomla 3.3.6 to Joomla 3.4.1. 
I see this error when I try to go the admin configuration page "JHtmlBehavior::formvalidator not found".
How to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a little code or a little more to go off of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing the Joomla 3.4.1 package thru' FTP upgrading and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to replace the code shown in your question

```
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
```

which is specified in the Joomla documentation.

Answer (score -1):

So i have got the same problem (500 JHtmlBehavior::formvalidator not found.) & it happened after update but in the admin panel. I fixed it

> file - /libraries/cms/html/behavior.php

```
You need to find smth like this 
    public static function formvalidation(){...}
and add the same method under formvalidation(){...} but with another name
    public static function formvalidator(){...}
```

Now you have two methods with different names ). I think this error happened because joomla updated partially